# Next button stops navigating before reaching end of gallery array

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website I am building for the construction company I work for. The main objective of this website is to show images of work we have completed. I have JavaScript code that should display hidden galleries of images and hide previous galleries using next/previous buttons. The next button works to move from the first to second gallery, but doesn't move from second to third and so on. Any idea why this is happening?

I have changed the currentIndex variable to a global variable, to eliminate starting the array at the first position every time I click the next button. Now, when I click the next button, there are no thumbnail images that show up.

Here is the updated JavaScript code:

```
window.onload = showImage(imgName);
var currentIndex = 0;

function showImage(imgName) 
{
    var largeImg = document.getElementById("large");
    var thePath = "images/";
    var theSource = thePath + imgName;

    largeImg.src = theSource;
    largeImg.alt = imgName;

}


function nextGall()
{
    var gallery = new Array();
    gallery = document.getElementsByClassName("gall");

    if(currentIndex > gallery.length)
    {
        currentIndex = gallery.length;
        document.getElementById("next").src = "images/nextEnd.jpg";
    }

    if (currentIndex > 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("previous").src = "images/previous.jpg";
    }

    currentIndex += 1;

    for (var x = 0; x < gallery.length; x++)
    {
        gallery[x].style.display = "none";
    }

    gallery[currentIndex].style.display = "block";
    return false;
}

function prevGall()
{
    var gallery = new Array();
    gallery = document.getElementsByClassName("gall");

    if(currentIndex <= 0)
    {
        currentIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById("previous").src = "images/previousEnd.jpg";
    }

    if(currentIndex < gallery.length)
    {
        document.getElementById("next").src = "images/next.jpg";
    }

    currentIndex -= 1;
    for (var x = 0; x < gallery.length; x++)
    {
        gallery[x].style.display = "none";
    }

    gallery[currentIndex].style.display = "block";
    return false;   
}
```

and here is a small snippet of the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Stamped</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="kc.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="concrete.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="page">

        <div id="links">
            <a href="kcweb.htm" class="menu">Home</a>
            <a href="about.htm" class="menu">About Us</a>
            <a href="contact.htm" class="menu">Contact Us</a>
            <a href="photos.htm" class="menu">Photos</a>
        </div>
        <div id="sign">
            <p><span>Klopstein Concrete</span><br />
            Everything Concrete...</p>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Klopstein-Concrete/256257947822?ref=hl"><img src="images/facebook.jpg" height="75" width="150" alt="facebook" class="sideLink"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.bbb.org/stlouis/business-reviews/concrete-contractors/klopstein-concrete-in-foley-mo-310436248#reasonrating"><img src="images/betterbusiness.jpg" height="75" width="150" alt="better business bureau" class="sideLink" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <h1>Stamped Concrete</h1>
            <div id="bigOne">
                <a href="#"><img id="large" src="images/Vince1.jpg" height="350" width="350" alt="Vince1.jpg" onclick="largePic(this);"/></a>
            </div>
            <div id="list">
                <h1 id="Gallery">Galleries</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li class="gallery"><a href="stamp.htm">Stamped Concrete</a></li>
                    <li class="gallery"><a href="exposed.htm">Exposed Aggregate</a></li>
                    <li class="gallery"><a href="stain.htm">Stained Concrete</a></li>
                    <li class="gallery"><a href="driveway.htm">Driveway/Walkway</a></li>
                    <li class="gallery"><a href="walls.htm">Walls</a></li>
                    <li class="gallery"><a href="countertop.htm">Countertops</a></li>
                    <li class="gallery"><a href="commercial.htm">Commercial</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="thumbs">
                <div id="gall1" class="gall">
                    <img src="images/Vince1.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="Vince1.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('Vince1.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/Vince2.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="Vince2.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('Vince2.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/Vince3.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="Vince3.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('Vince3.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/Vince4.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="Vince4.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('Vince4.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/Vince5.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="Vince5.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('Vince5.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/Vince6.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="Vince6.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('Vince6.jpg');"/>
                </div>
                <div id="gall2" class="gall">
                    <img src="images/Martin1.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="Martin1.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('Martin1.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/Martin2.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="Martin2.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('Martin2.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/Martin3.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="Martin3.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('Martin3.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/Martin4.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="Martin4.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('Martin4.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/Martin5.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="Martin5.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('Martin5.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/zach.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="zach.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('zach.jpg');"/>
                </div>
                <div id="gall3" class="gall">
                    <img src="images/arch1.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="arch1.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('arch1.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/arch2.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="arch2.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('arch2.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/arch3.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="arch3.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('arch3.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/arch4.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="arch1.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('arch4.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/collin1.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="collin1.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('collin1.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/collin2.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="collin2.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('collin2.jpg');"/>
                </div>
                <div id="gall4" class="gall">
                    <img src="images/anderson1.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="anderson1.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('anderson1.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/anderson2.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="anderson2.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('anderson2.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/anderson3.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="anderson3.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('anderson3.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/anderson4.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="anderson4.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('anderson4.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/anderson5.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="anderson5.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('anderson5.jpg');"/>
                    <img src="images/anderson6.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="anderson6.jpg" onmouseover="showImage('anderson6.jpg');"/>
                </div>
<div id="navigate">
                    <img id="previous" src="images/previous.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="previous" onclick="return prevGall();"/>
                    <img id="next" src="images/next.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="next" onclick="return nextGall();"/>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = showImage(imgName);
var currentIndex = 0,
    gallery = new Array(); 
    gallery = document.getElementsByClassName("gall"); // unless you're going to load galleries by AJAX, you do not need to count how many galleries are there every time lanuching a function

function showImage(imgName) 
{
    var largeImg = document.getElementById("large");
    var thePath = "images/";
    var theSource = thePath + imgName;

    largeImg.src = theSource;
    largeImg.alt = imgName;
}


function nextGall()
{
    var nextGalleryIndex = currentIndex + 1;

    if(nextGalleryIndex > gallery.length)
    {
        currentIndex = gallery.length; //if we reached the end of gallery, then it will always stay on LAST gallery index
    }
    else if(nextGalleryIndex < gallery.length)
    {
      for (var x = 0; x < gallery.length; x++)
      {
          gallery[x].style.display = "none";
      }
      gallery[nextGalleryIndex].style.display = "block";
      currentIndex = nextGalleryIndex;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Now it isn't changing the galleries at all. I just don't understand why my code would move from the gallery displayed when the page is loaded to the next gallery of images but, will not continue to navigate to the third, fourth, fifth and so on.

Comment: I double checked the code - the code i provided works :) - if you have problems comment out the function showImage(). 
the problem with your solution is that each time you call a nextGall() function you SET CURRENT GALLERY to 0, and then adds one, which means current gallery will always be 1 IN function.

Comment: I copied and pasted this into my file. The page will not navigate through the image galleries. I moved the currentIndex and gallery variables from global to local(into the nextGall()) and I am having the same problem. The navigation stops after the second image gallery. Again, scratching my head as to why it stops here. Am I overlooking something in the HTML code?

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying about setting the current gallery to 0 every time I hit the next button. Why is my code not recognizing the variables when they are global variables? When I make them global variables, the next button does not navigate at all.

Comment: I would need to see how did you edited the code you have right now to explain more, if the global variables are not recognized, it means they are not properly initialized (for example you initialize them BEFORE galleries load)